# Gulp 3 to 4 migration : gulp serve won't start the http server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gulp

In an AngularJS 1.7 project, I've managed to migrate my gulp configuration files from 3.9 to 4.0.2, but the http server won't start with a "gulp serve"

I've :

- Converted all the dependencies to a "series" task. I used series everywhere, as I think it's safer (and slower) than using parallel execution.

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

to

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['clean']), function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

- Reorder the require('./gulp/somefile.js') manually so that tasks are defined before being called. (before it was loaded by a loop)
- within each files put the function definition before the task call them

When I do a "gulp serve", I can see the build output showing the same 'normal' errors I had before migration (non angularjs lib added manually), and some new warning from bootstrap-sass about deprecated division.

After the build part, I would expect a local server to start on port 3000, Chrome being launched with the web UI i'm developping being displayed and my REST call being proxied to a local apache/php server, but well, it doesn't start, no error/warning, nothing.

```
[00:41:33] Finished 'styles' after 1.6 s
[00:41:33] Finished 'inject' after 2.31 s
[00:41:33] Finished 'watch' after 2.31 s
[00:41:33] Finished 'serve' after 2.31 s
```

The configuration files are here : https://github.com/dev-mansonthomas/RedCrossQuest/tree/ComposerLibUpdate/client

gulp.js
and then all files in the gulp sub directory.

Answer (score 2):

`gulp.start` was never really intended for end users and is unneccesary with `gulp.series`.  I wouldn't doubt support for it was removed from v4.  Just use:

```js
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'build'));
```

Comment: I've updated (reverted) the version "http-proxy-middleware" to 0.9.1 (the version it was before the migration) and 0.21.0 + your suggestion, but the server still doesn't start

Comment: When I did the migration, I've updated all libs to latest version (I'm optimistic :grin:), but the http-proxy-middleware seems to have change in the way it's instantiated